# Convert txt file to table

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I would like to convert this .txt file:
[image]

The [ ] indicate a row.
The , separates the rows.

I want to convert this into a matrix.

How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `Import[#, "Text"]&` and then:

```
ImportString["[" <> # <> "]", "JSON"] & @ "[123.123,12,123],[1.1,1.2,3]"
```

> ```
> {{123.123`, 12, 123}, {1.1`, 1.2`, 3}}
> ```

Comment: Side note: consistent fail of `TextRecognize` , it converts all right brackets to 1's in image example given.